# ruby - How can I associate text with a construction point with sketchup api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sketchup

I'm developing a sketchup plugin with ruby, I have coded the parsing process succesfully and I got the cpoints from csv file to sketchup. The csv file also contains a description within coordinates of every point like : `["15461.545", "845152.56", "5464.59", "tower1"]`.
I want to get the `tower1` as a text associated to every point.

How can I do that ?

*PS : You don't need to get the `tower1` from the array, i've already done that. I have it now in an independant variable like :
`desc_array = ["tower1", "beacon48", "anna55", ...]`*

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that by

> @@todraw_su.each do |todraw|
>
> @@desc_array.each do |desc|
>
> @model.entities.add_text desc, todraw
>
> end
>
> end

But I found a problem with each statement, it loops for every `todraw` in `desc`
If you know how I can do it, answer on this question [Each statement inside another each malfunctions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754912/ruby-each-statement-inside-another-each-malfunction)