# Each statement inside another each malfunctions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sketchup

I'm coding a Google sketchup plugin with Ruby, and I faced a little problem.  I have an array containing descriptions of every point like:

```
desc_array = ["anna ", "anna 45", "anna689", "anna36", "anna 888", "anna ",...]
```

The array containing every point's coordinates is:

```
todraw_su = [
  [-16.23317, -16.530533, 99.276929],
  [-25.142825, -12.476601, 99.237414],
  [-32.716122, -5.92341, 99.187951],
  [-38.964589, 4.181119, 99.182358],
  [-41.351064, 18.350418, 99.453714],
  [-40.797511, 33.987519, 99.697253],
  ...
]
```

I want to add a text in Google sketchup for each point. According to the Sketchup API this can be done by:

```
Sketchup.active_model.entities.add_text "This is the text", [x, y, z]
```

I tried:

```
todraw_su.each {|todraw| desc_array.each {|desc| Sketchup.active_model.entities.add_text desc,todraw }}
```

But, it gave me something unexpected, as it returns all the elements in `desc_array` for every element in `to_draw`.

What I want is every element in `desc_array` for every element in `to_draw`.

Comment: A better title for this would be something like "match up elements from two Arrays".

Comment: Checkout http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip

Comment: Your code does exactly what it says; for each and every element of `todraw_su` it iterates over each element in `desc_array` i.e. all of them. This is definitely not a "malfunction".  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[desc_array, todraw_su].transpose.each do |desc, coord|
  # ...
end
```

You can also do this with `#zip` like...

```
desc_array.zip(todraw_su).each do |desc, coord|
  # ...
end
```

With the *#zip* technique, the result will always have the first array's dimension, with the second truncated or nil-padded as needed. This may or may not be TRT. Transpose will raise *IndexError* in that case.